# Printing a list of objects of user defined class

Tags: python

So I have a class, called `Vertex`.

```
class Vertex:
    '''
    This class is the vertex class. It represents a vertex.
    '''

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        self.neighbours = []

    def __str__(self):
        return("Vertex "+str(self.label)+":"+str(self.neighbours))
```

I want to print a list of objects of this class, like this:

```
x = [Vertex(1), Vertex(2)]
print x
```

but it shows me output like this:

```
[<__main__.Vertex instance at 0xb76ed84c>, <__main__.Vertex instance at 0xb76ed86c>]
```

Actually, I wanted to print the value of `Vertex.label` for each object.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If you just want to print the label for each object, you could use a loop or a list comprehension:

```
print [vertex.label for vertex in x]
```

But to answer your original question, you need to define the `__repr__` method to get the list output right. It could be something as simple as this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self)
```

Answer (score 22):

If you want a little more infos in addition of Daniel Roseman answer:

`__repr__` and `__str__` are two different things in python. (note, however, that if you have defined only `__repr__`, a call to `class.__str__` will translate into a call to `class.__repr__`)

The goal of `__repr__` is to be unambiguous. Plus, whenerver possible, you should define repr so that(in your case) `eval(repr(instance)) == instance`

On the other hand, the goal of `__str__` is to be readable; so it matter if you have to print the instance on screen (for the user, probably), if you don't need to do it, then do not implement it (and again, if str in not implemented will be called repr)

Plus, when type things in the Idle interpreter, it automatically calls the repr representation of your object. Or when you print a list, it calls `list.__str__` (which is identical to `list.__repr__`) that calls in his turn the repr representaion of any element the list contains. This explains the behaviour you get and hopefully how to fix it

Comment: I see, so the interpreter is recursively calling __repr__() on any object within the list.. is that right?

Comment: no, the interpreter is calling list.__str__() (or repr, it depend, but that's the same thing) and list.__str__ returns a string composed by calling repr of all the objects that the list contains

Answer (score -1):

```
def __ str __ (self):
    return f"Vertex: {self.label} {self.neighbours}"

#In most cases, this is probably the easiest and cleanest way to do it. Not fully sure how this code will interact with your list []. Lastly, any words or commas needed, just add them between the brackets; no further quotes needed.
```