# Python3 Initializing class objects to different variables and storing them in a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to build a class to create monsters(npc) and then initialize their values to different npc[var] and then create 5 of each and add them to a list and then print the list to see it is there.
How should I go about this?

My code is shown below.

```
class npc:
    def __init__(self, name, health, attack, defense, loot, gold):
        self.n = name
        self.h = health
        self.a = attack
        self.d = defense
        self.l = loot
        self.g = gold
class hero:
    def __init__(self, health, attack, defense, gold):

        self.health = health
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.gold = gold
npc1 = npc()
npc1.name = "Goblin"; npc1.health = 10; npc1.attack = 10; npc1.defense = 10
npc1.loot= "goblin_armor"; npc1.gold = 10
npc2 = npc()
npc1.name = "Goblin"; npc1.health = 10; npc1.attack = 10; npc1.defense = 10
npc1.loot= "goblin_armor"; npc1.gold = 10
npc3 = npc()
npc1.name = "Goblin"; npc1.health = 10; npc1.attack = 10; npc1.defense = 10
npc1.loot= "goblin_armor"; npc1.gold = 10
npc4 = npc()
npc1.name = "Goblin"; npc1.health = 10; npc1.attack = 10; npc1.defense = 10
npc1.loot= "goblin_armor"; npc1.gold = 10
npc5 = npc()
npc1.name = "Goblin"; npc1.health = 10; npc1.attack = 10; npc1.defense = 10
npc1.loot= "goblin_armor"; npc1.gold = 10


monsters = []

for i in range(0,5):
    monsters.append(npc1)
for i in range(6,10):
    monsters.append(npc2)
for i in range(11,15):
    monsters.append(npc3)
for i in range(16,20):
    monsters.append(npc4)
for i in range(21,25):
    monsters.append(npc5)

print (monsters)
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: You defined `__init__`, with many parameters, so why are you not using it? Is there an error that says something like 7 arguments expected, 1 given?

Comment: You should look up some basic examples how to write classes in python

Answer (score 0):

```
class npc:
    def __init__(self, name, health, attack, defense, loot, gold):
        self.n = name
        self.h = health
        self.a = attack
        self.d = defense
        self.l = loot
        self.g = gold

npc1 = npc()
```

This alone should error with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 10, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 7 arguments (1 given)
```

You need to use the constructor correctly

```
npc1 = npc("Goblin", 10, 10, 10, "goblin_armor", 10)
print(npc1.n) # Goblin
```

Note: `npc1.n` is the variable because you've set `self.n` instead of `self.name`... variables can be more than one letter

---

Or don't use a constructor at all

```
class npc:
  pass

npc2 = npc()
npc2.name = "Goblin"; npc2.health = 10; npc2.attack = 10; npc2.defense = 10
npc2.loot= "goblin_armor"; npc2.gold = 10

print(npc2.name) # Goblin
```

---

If using the second approach - you'll want to set the values for `npc2` instead of `npc1`.

> ```
> npc2 = npc()
> npc1.name = "Goblin"; npc1.health = 10; npc1.attack = 10; npc1.defense = 10
> npc1.loot= "goblin_armor"; npc1.gold = 10
> ```

---

Then instead of adding many copies of the same object, you need to create new instances when you add to the list.

```
monsters = []

for i in range(0,5):
    next_npc = npc(<values_here>)
    monsters.append(next_npc)
```

Otherwise, if you edited `monsters[0].name`, then `monsters[1:4].name` values would also change

Comment: When I print the list it prints 

[<__main__.npc object at 0x101806eb8>, <__main__.npc object at 0x101806ef0>, <__main__.npc object at 0x101806f28>, <__main__.npc object at 0x101806f60>, <__main__.npc obj etc.....

Comment: Yup. To be expected. Look at this question for some info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933964/printing-a-list-of-objects-of-user-defined-class