# appending to a List that is an instance of a class Python

Tags: python, list, class, oop, append

I want that everytime an instance is created, it is added to a list.
I have already done it this way using the list inside the class but OUTSIDE the constructor :

```
Class matriculation:
    students = []
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number = number
        matriculation.students.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def show(cls):
        for student in matriculation.students:
            print(student.number, end= " ")
        print("\n") 
def main():
    s1 = matriculation(1)
    s2 = matriculation(2)
    #print the list students
    matriculation.show() #here I am calling the class method
```

So this works, but now I want that the list to be inside the  constructor. I thought doing the same would work but when trying to print I get an error: type object 'course' has no attribute 'course_li'.which makes sense but I don´t want the list to be passed as an attribute.

```
Class course:
    def __init__(self,course):
        self.course = course
        self.course_li = []
        self.course_li.append(self)

def main():
    c1 = course("Math")
    c2 = course("History")
    #this is how you print the content but it gives an error:
    for subject in course.course_li: 
        print(subject.course, end= " ")
```

so I don´t know if  I am in fact adding to the course_li or not.
closest to this behaviour I have found is an example here [Printing a list of objects of user defined class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933964/printing-a-list-of-objects-of-user-defined-class)
but the difference is that here the list is being passed as an attribute and I don´t want that. I want the append to be done automatically everytime a new instance is created.Can that be done this way?
I know it can be done so far already with the list inside the main function, as a global variable, and inside the class outside the constructor, but maybe not inside the constructor?or is my for loop the one that is wrong?

I am doing this in preparation for an exam, where one of our tasks was doing this so it is very probable the exam will ask variations of doing the same thing in different conditions.

Comment: Your first snippet seems right where `students` is an attribute of the class. Is there something wrong with this? Adding something inside the `__init__()` method is doing it at the wrong time and resets the attribute back to an empty list each time.

Comment: You should respect the Python convention of using capitalized names for classes. In your second example, using the same name for the class and the second parameter to `__init__` doesn't help readability. Anyway, I don't really get what you are trying to do here: making the list of instances an instance attribute rather than a class attribute doesn't really make sense. Maybe you need some clarity about these notions?