# How do I print a list with the __str__() method

Tags: python

I have 2 lists that I wanted to merge together (witch contained 'class' objects), so I tried using the _*str*_() method but it didn't work

I made this class that would give each card a color and number and then tried to use the _*str*_() function

```
#create class
class card:
  def __init__(self, color, number):
    self.color = color
    self.number = number
  def __str__(self):
    return (self.color, self.number)
```

then I made a list of 'class' objects using loops

```
red_cards = [(card("red",i) for i in range(1,10))]
blue_cards = [(card("blue",i) for i in range(1,10))]
```

then I merged the list

```
cards_in_deck = red_cards + blue_cards
```

and then I tried to print it using the _*str*_() method

```
print(cards_in_deck.__str__)
```

and it returned this

```
<method-wrapper '__str__' of list object at 0x7f5d7d992a00>
```

I tried the answer below but I was wondering: how do I print them out of the `main()` without getting a 'generator' object, if I do do that it will give out a 'generator' object, it will even error when I try to print the color or number saying there is no color and number.

Comment: Did you mean: `print(cards_in_deck)`? Or did you mean to write: `def __repr__(self): ...` for your class?

Comment: `print(cards_in_deck)` - the list, not the`__str__` method of the list. Note that printing a list this way will use the `__repr__` of the list items, not their `__str__`.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933964/printing-a-list-of-objects-of-user-defined-class) help at all?

Comment: Also you have a bug in the `list of 'class' objects`.  There is an extra set of () making it a list containing a generator.  Use `[...]` not `[(...)]`.

Comment: `__repr__` and `__str__` should also return *strings* not a tuple as you have.

Answer (score 0):

The `__str__` method should return a string representation of the object. In your case, it returns a tuple, which is incorrect. You need to format the output as a string:

```
class Card:

    def __init__(self, color, number):
        self.color = color
        self.number = number

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.color} {self.number}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Card(color='{self.color}', number={self.number})"


def main():
    red_cards = [Card('red', i) for i in range(1, 10)]
    blue_cards = [Card('blue', i) for i in range(1, 10)]
    cards_in_deck = red_cards + blue_cards
    for card in cards_in_deck:
        print(card)  # Uses __str__ method
    print(cards_in_deck)  # Uses __repr__ method


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
red 1
red 2
red 3
red 4
red 5
red 6
red 7
red 8
red 9
blue 1
blue 2
blue 3
blue 4
blue 5
blue 6
blue 7
blue 8
blue 9
[Card(color='red', number=1), Card(color='red', number=2), Card(color='red', number=3), Card(color='red', number=4), Card(color='red', number=5), Card(color='red', number=6), Card(color='red', number=7), Card(color='red', number=8), Card(color='red', number=9), Card(color='blue', number=1), Card(color='blue', number=2), Card(color='blue', number=3), Card(color='blue', number=4), Card(color='blue', number=5), Card(color='blue', number=6), Card(color='blue', number=7), Card(color='blue', number=8), Card(color='blue', number=9)]
```